# How to copy Span<byte> contents to location pointed by IntPtr?

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged-memory

I have an instance of `Span<byte>` which I would like to copy to unmanaged memory pointed by `IntPtr`. If I had a `byte[]`, this would be an easy job, just call `Marshal.Copy`:

[image]

I know I can convert `Span<byte>` to `byte[]` by calling `ToArray`, but that would require additional allocation, which I am trying to avoid. Is there any clean, non-allocating (also not using `unsafe` if possible) way to copy contents of `Span<byte>` to unmanaged memory pointed by `IntPtr`?

Comment: Well, you could perhaps turn your IntPtr into a pointer into a Span<byte> (requiring unsafe context) and then copy into it... (see also here for a related discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21370)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thank you for the solution. Is there any way to maybe not require `unsafe`?

Comment: No, currently not (or rather, i don't know of any dirty trick that would allow you to do so). As already linked, see the related discussion that contains arguments from some .NET Platform members of why they don't see much usefulness in offering a direct translation from IntPtr to Span<T>. At least for the time being...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the *IntPtr* into a *Span<byte>* will allow copying the source span into the span representing the unmanaged buffer.

However, a *Span<T>* cannot be directly derived from an IntPtr, but rather requires  turning the *IntPtr* into a `void*` pointer first and then creating a *Span<T>* from that pointer:

```
var spanUnmanagedBuffer = new Span<byte>(intPtrUnmanagedBuffer.ToPointer(), sizeUnmanagedBuffer);
```

Creating a *Span<T>* this way requires `unsafe` context, unfortunately.